# Why does 15.04 gnome-terminal not have the Unity-style scrollbars?

Tags: unity, 15.04, gnome-terminal, overlay-scrollbars

I really like the "overlay-scrollbars" that were introduced in Unity. Here is a screenshot:
[image: Unity scrollbar]

In 14.04, the gnome-terminal had overlay-scrollbars. But I installed 15.04 (full install, not update) and now gnome-terminal has the old-style scrollbars. The old-style looks like this:

[image: Old-style scrollbar]

Is there anything I can do to get the overlay-scrollbar in gnome-terminal on 15.04? Did Ubuntu remove this style scrollbar from gnome-terminal or is there something wrong with my installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing the `overlay-scrollbar` type typing in the following from a terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install overlay-scrollbar
```

From a terminal type in the following to enable the scrollbar overlays:

```
gsettings reset com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode overlay-auto
```

To disable the scrollbar overlays, type in:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode normal
```

Hope this helps. **;)**

Comment: Have you tested this on 15.04? I don't have that schema available.

Comment: @user308393 Yes, I have tried this on a clean 15.04 installation, and it works fine.

Comment: Is there a way to get that schema installed or something? Is there a package that gives more enhanced dconf editor control or something?

Comment: @user308393 let me find that for you.

Comment: @user308393 updated with installing the scrollbar overlay.

Comment: @user308393 you're very welcome!

Comment: Shouldn't `gsettings reset com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode overlay-auto` be `gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode overlay-auto`?